# Use of italics versus quotes for terms

Tags: italics

Something I find a little tricky is whether to use italics or quotes for terms. In most cases, the terms I cite are not used repeatedly, but are one-time mentions.

So, for example, we have the following sentence:

> The crest or *kamon* of the Tokugawa clan was the *Aoi* ("hollyhock").

So, here we have a couple of different terms that I have italicized, but then put the translation in quotes. Alternatively, I guess I could have used quotes, then put 'hollyhock' in single quotes. In that case, it would read like this:

> The crest or "kamon" of the Tokugawa clan was the "Aoi" ('hollyhock').

It starts to get confusing when I have a sentence with a lot of different terms and translations in it. Is there a general set of rules or policies that are advisable in such cases?

Comment: I prefer the first sentence using *italicization*. I think that's also the convention in the Chicago Manual and APA style.

Comment: If you are using italics, there is no reason to *also* use quotation marks. The difference between italics in one place and roman text in the other is sufficient. And I prefer italics in general. In other words, I like your first version better; however, I would remove the quotation marks from the word in parentheses.

Comment: The crest or *kamon* of the Tokugawa clan was the *Aoi* (hollyhock).

Comment: There is no single agreed-upon set of rules for formatting, typography, punctuation; these are matters of style. You should therefore adhere to the discipline of your editor, publication, or organization, or in the absence of a house style, adopt a [style manual](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2579) appropriate to your audience and tastes and be consistent in its application.